# Extra trailing closure passed in call error while using DynamoDB with Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I was trying to use DynamoDB with swift for a MacOS application. The problem is that, even when copying the function suggested by the AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/examples-ddb-items.html), I am getting the error:

`Extra trailing closure passed in call`

Example function:

```
func getDynamoDbItem(dynamoDbClient: DynamoDbClient,
                     nameOfTable: String,
                     keyName: String,
                     keyVal: String) {
    let keyToGet = [keyName : DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue.s(keyVal)]
    dynamoDbClient.getItem(input: GetItemInput(key: keyToGet, tableName: nameOfTable)) { result in
        switch(result) {
        case .success(let response):
            guard let numbersMap = response.item else {
                return
            }
            for returnedKey in numbersMap {
                print("\(returnedKey.key) : \(returnedKey.value)")
            }
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: func getDynamoDbItem(dynamoDbClient: DynamoDBClient,
                         nameOfTable: String,
                         keyName: String,
                         keyVal: String) async {
            
            let keyToGet = GetItemInput(key: [keyName : DynamoDBClientTypes.AttributeValue.s(keyVal)], tableName: nameOfTable)
        do {

             let result = try await dynamoDbClient.getItem(input: keyToGet)
            print("response \(result)")
            
        } catch {
        }
            }
Error: SLSTransaction timed out 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on the provided link is outdated. The newer version of the dependency is already using async requests.

```
func getDynamoDbItem(dynamoDbClient: DynamoDbClient,
                     nameOfTable: String,
                     keyName: String,
                     keyVal: String) async {
    do {
        
        let keyToGet = [keyName : DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue.s(keyVal)]
        let result = try await dynamoDbClient.getItem(input: GetItemInput(key: keyToGet, tableName: nameOfTable))
        
        // use result
        
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
    
}
```

Edit:

```
private var dynamoDBResponseSubject = PassthroughSubject<GetItemOutputResponse, Error>()
var dynamoDBResponse: AnyPublisher<GetItemOutputResponse, Error> { dynamoDBResponseSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher() }


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Task {
        getDynamoDbItem(dynamoDbClient: dynamoDbClient, nameOfTable: "nameOfTable", keyName: "keyName", keyVal: "keyVal")
    }
}


func getDynamoDbItem(dynamoDbClient: DynamoDbClient,
                     nameOfTable: String,
                     keyName: String,
                     keyVal: String) {
        do {
            
            let keyToGet = [keyName : DynamoDbClientTypes.AttributeValue.s(keyVal)]
            let result = try await dynamoDbClient.getItem(input: GetItemInput(key: keyToGet, tableName: nameOfTable))
            dynamoDBResponseSubject.send(result)                
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
}
```

Or you can remove the async from the `getDynamoDbItem...` method and add the `do { ... } catch { ... }` block within a Task

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using `await` and `async`? Suppose I have to call this method inside of my `viewDidLoad()`, then also my `viewDidLoad()` should be `async` and then of course it is not overriding any method from the superclass

Comment: The method itself is async but you can add it within a `Task { //aws dynamo db request logic }` and work with a publisher to get the info when the task is done.

Comment: @Kronos_Rob make function async and call like this in viewdidload
  Task {
            await getDynamoDbItem(dynamoDbClient: handler.ddbClient!, nameOfTable: "ServerVersion", keyName: "VersionID", keyVal: "1.0.2.321")
            }

Comment: @LoVo I called this method but getting error SLSTransaction timed out 4

Comment: @AG007 When your request times out, you should check if your connection to the AWS is configured correct. Plz check: key, secrets, region, ... If everything is correct check if you need to increase the max timeout.

Comment: @LoVo It would be great if u can give me code snippet how I can set access, secrete,region . Because as per document I have added this in Environment Variable.

And as u said how I can increase request time out also.

Comment: @AG007 You should check their documentation, they have some examples you might want to check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-swift/latest/developer-guide/swift_dynamodb_code_examples.html

Comment: @LoVo this I tried but problem is I am not able to configure access and seceretkey, region via code in AppDelegate